# String variable expansion in debug macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

I am trying to write a debug macro in the common subset of C and C++.  This is what I've come up with so far:

```
#define OUTPUT_ERROR(...) printf("%s(%d) : %s() : %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, #__VA_ARGS__)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to give it variables to output. Is there any way to force a variable to be expanded at runtime? For example:

```
OUTPUT_ERROR("%s was broken", my_var);
```

or simply in place

```
OUTPUT_ERROR(my_var + "some text");
```

Comment: avoid training semicolon in your macro definition.

Comment: `printf` doesn't recursively format strings

Comment: Macros and `printf` tend to be very C-oriented and less C++. Please try to refrain to add language tags that you don't actually use. If you're programming in C then don't add the C++ even if the solution or the code could be used in C++.

Comment: As for a solution to your problem, consider using a two-step process: One to format the output according to your arguments, and then one to actually print the output.

Comment: However, considering this is C++, how about taking advantage of a library like [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) that offers proper type safety?

Comment: Thx Jean-Francois Fabre, I do not make macros often. For libraries and such, I have specific requirements that means I am coding in the c++ language only, no stl, no libraries.

Comment: But `printf` *is* part of the standard library. What is the reason you then can't use the rest of the standard library (since it will be linked in with whatever application your building anyway)? If you program in C++, then your life will be so much easier if you use the standard facilities that come with the language.

Comment: @scx, I'm not following what you're willing to use and what not.  Are you trying to say that you are actually writing C, *which is a different language from C++*?  Or are you perhaps saying that you are restricting yourself to the common subset of C and C++?

Comment: @scx, writing for the common subset of C and C++ is *very different* and considerably more difficult than writing normally for either one language or the other.  The reason these comments went the direction they did is largely that the question does not clearly state the true question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking to define a macro prepending some debugging information to your formatted log.

To achieve this, you can use the following macro :

```
#define LOG(format, ...) \
printf("%s(%d) : %s() " format, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

This way `LOG("%d", 123)` will expand to `printf("%s(%d) : %s() " "%s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, 123)`.
As consecutive string literals are merged (`"a" "b"` is equivalent to `"ab"`), the `printf` format is correctly built.

Also note the use of `, ## __VA_ARGS__`. This is a GNU extension (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) that allows empty variadic arguments.

This technique will however fail if `format` is not a string literal.
See an example here : http://ideone.com/gMnaES

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're trying to cram too much into one `printf()` call.  You don't need to do that.  In particular, to support usage such as your first example:

> ```
> OUTPUT_ERROR("%s was broken", my_var);
> ```

you could easily split the output over multiple `printf()` calls with a macro like this:

```
#define OUTPUT_ERROR(...) do { \
  printf("%s(%d) : %s() : ", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__); \
  printf(__VA_ARGS__); \
  putchar('\n'); \
} while (0)
```